# How can I Read the file with Lua doing search filter and store the entries as a variable

Tags: lua

So I want to read a text file with the following format:

```lua
Bob, G92f22f, Fggggfdff32
Rob, f3h9123, fdsgfdsg3
Sally, f2g4g, g3g3hgdsd
```

I want a simple Lua program that can filter out say "bob" and then say throw the data into a variable to use in a program.

```lua
a = Bob
b = G92f22f
c = Fggggfdff32
```

I assume then I could do
`print(a,b,c)`

Still quite new to Lua having a heck of a time with anything read / variable though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the [`io`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8) and [`string`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4) modules; they handle things like reading from / writing to files and doing pattern matching on strings.

Luas pattern matching is a bit simple compared to the regular expressions most modern languages use, but from what I see in your example, you could probably match a "word" as `[^, ]+`, that is, *one or more characters that aren't a comma or a space*